# how to sort the target word by value of dictionary and count associated words?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two text files, one is sample.txt and the other is common.txt. First I would like to remove common words from sample.txt. Common words are found in common.txt and in the code sample.txt has been modified as desired. common.txt is:

```
a
about
after
again
against
ago
all
along
also
always
an
and
another
any
are
around
as
at
away
back
be
because
been
before
began
being
between
both
but
by
came
can
come
could
course
day
days
did
do
down
each
end
even
ever
every
first
for
four
from
get
give
go
going
good
got
great
had
half
has
have
he
head
her
here
him
his
house
how
hundred
i
if
in
into
is
it
its
just
know
last
left
life
like
little
long
look
made
make
man
many
may
me
men
might
miles
more
most
mr
much
must
my
never
new
next
no
not
nothing
now
of
off
old
on
once
one
only
or
other
our
out
over
own
people
pilot
place
put
right
said
same
saw
say
says
see
seen
she
should
since
so
some
state
still
such
take
tell
than
that
the
their
them
then
there
these
they
thing
think
this
those
thousand
three
through
time
times
to
told
too
took
two
under
up
upon
us
use
used
very
want
was
way
we
well
went
were
what
when
where
which
while
who
will
with
without
work
world
would
year
years
yes
yet
you
young
your
```

sample.txt is:

```
    THE Mississippi is well worth reading about. It is not a commonplace
river, but on the contrary is in all ways remarkable. Considering the
Missouri its main branch, it is the longest river in the world--four
thousand three hundred miles. It seems safe to say that it is also the
crookedest river in the world, since in one part of its journey it uses
up one thousand three hundred miles to cover the same ground that the
crow would fly over in six hundred and seventy-five. It discharges three
times as much water as the St. Lawrence, twenty-five times as much
as the Rhine, and three hundred and thirty-eight times as much as the
Thames. No other river has so vast a drainage-basin: it draws its water
supply from twenty-eight States and Territories; from Delaware, on the
Atlantic seaboard, and from all the country between that and Idaho on
the Pacific slope--a spread of forty-five degrees of longitude. The
Mississippi receives and carries to the Gulf water from fifty-four
subordinate rivers that are navigable by steamboats, and from some
hundreds that are navigable by flats and keels. The area of its
drainage-basin is as great as the combined areas of England, Wales,
Scotland, Ireland, France, Spain, Portugal, Germany, Austria, Italy,
and Turkey; and almost all this wide region is fertile; the Mississippi
valley, proper, is exceptionally so.
```

after removing the common words, I need to break it into sentences and use "." as full stop and count appearance of target word in sentences. Also, need to create profile for target word to show associated words and their counts. For example, if "river" is the target word, the associated words include "commonplace", "contrary" and so on that happen in the same sentence (within a full stop) with "river". The desired output is listed in descending order:

```
river 4
     ground: 1
     journey: 1
     longitude: 1
     main: 1
     world--four: 1
     contrary: 1
     cover: 1
     ...
mississippi 3
     area: 1
     steamboats: 1
     germany: 1
     reading: 1
     france: 1
     proper: 1
     ...
```

Three dots mean the associated words should be more and are not listed in here. And now here is the coding so far:

```
def open_file(file):
file = "/Users/apple/Documents/sample.txt"
file1 = "/Users/apple/Documents/common.txt"
with open(file1, "r") as f:  
    common_words = {i.strip() for i in f}  

punctionmark = ":;,'\"."   
trans_table = str.maketrans(punctionmark, " " * len(punctionmark))

word_counter = {} 
with open(file, "r") as f: 
    for line in f: 
        for word in line.translate(trans_table).split(): 
            if word.lower() not in common_words: 
                word_counter[word.lower()] = word_counter.get(word, 0) + 1 
                #print(word_counter)

print("\n".join("{} {}".format(w, c) for w, c in word_counter.items()))
```

And my output now is:

```
mississipi 1
reading 1
about 1
commonplace 1
river 4
.
.
.
```

And so far I have counted the occurrence of target word but stuck to sort the target words in descending order and to get the counts for their associated words. Anyone can provide solution without importing other modules? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to tokenize, filter, and group the text into sentences, and then traverse your structure of target and associated words to find the final counts:

```
import re, string
from collections import namedtuple
import itertools
stop_words = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
text = open('filename.txt').read()
grammar = {'punctuation':string.punctuation, 'stopword':stop_words}
token = namedtuple('token', ['name', 'value'])
tokenized_file = [token((lambda x:'word' if not x else x[0])([a for a, b in grammar.items() if i.lower() in b]), i) for i in re.findall('\w+|\!|\-|\.|;|,:', text)]
filtered_file = [i for i in tokenized_file if i.name != 'stopword']
grouped_data = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(filtered_file, key=lambda x:x.value not in '!.?')]
text_with_sentences = ' '.join([' '.join([c.value for c in grouped_data[i]])+grouped_data[i+1][0].value for i in range(0, len(grouped_data), 2)])
```

Currently, the result of `text_with_sentences` is:

```
'Mississippi worth reading. commonplace river contrary ways remarkable. Considering Missouri main branch longest river - -. seems safe crookedest river part journey uses cover ground crow fly six seventy - five. discharges water St. Lawrence twenty - five Rhine thirty - eight Thames. river vast drainage - basin draws water supply twenty - eight States Territories ; Delaware Atlantic seaboard country Idaho Pacific slope - - spread forty - five degrees longitude. Mississippi receives carries Gulf water fifty - subordinate rivers navigable steamboats hundreds navigable flats keels. area drainage - basin combined areas England Wales Scotland Ireland France Spain Portugal Germany Austria Italy Turkey ; almost wide region fertile ; Mississippi valley proper exceptionally.'
```

---

To find the counts for the keyword profiling, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
counts = collections.Counter(map(str.lower, re.findall('[\w\-]+', text)))
structure = [['river', ['ground', 'journey', 'longitude', 'main', 'world--four', 'contrary', 'cover']], ['mississippi', ['area', 'steamboats', 'germany', 'reading', 'france', 'proper']]]
new_structure = [{'keyword':counts.get(a, 0), 'associated':{i:counts.get(i, 0) for i in b}} for a, b in structure]
```

Output:

```
[{'associated': {'cover': 1, 'longitude': 1, 'journey': 1, 'contrary': 1, 'main': 1, 'world--four': 1, 'ground': 1}, 'keyword': 4}, {'associated': {'area': 1, 'france': 1, 'germany': 1, 'proper': 1, 'reading': 1, 'steamboats': 1}, 'keyword': 3}]
```

---

Without using any modules, `str.split` can be used:

```
words = [[i[:-1], i[-1]] if i[-1] in string.punctuation else [i] for i in text.split()]
new_words = [i for b in words for i in b if i.lower() not in stop_words]
def find_groups(d, _pivot = '.'):
   current = [] 
   for i in d: 
     if i == _pivot:
       yield ' '.join(current)+'.'
       current = []
     else:
       current.append(i)

print(list(find_groups(new_words)))
counts = {}
for i in new_words:
   if i.lower() not in counts:
     counts[i.lower()] = 1
   else:
     counts[i.lower()] += 1

structure = [['river', ['ground', 'journey', 'longitude', 'main', 'world--four', 'contrary', 'cover']], ['mississippi', ['area', 'steamboats', 'germany', 'reading', 'france', 'proper']]]
new_structure = [{'keyword':counts.get(a, 0), 'associated':{i:counts.get(i, 0) for i in b}} for a, b in structure]
```

Output:

```
['Mississippi worth reading.', 'commonplace river , contrary ways remarkable.', 'Considering Missouri main branch , longest river world--four.', 'seems safe crookedest river , part journey uses cover ground crow fly six seventy-five.', 'discharges water St.', 'Lawrence , twenty-five Rhine , thirty-eight Thames.', 'river vast drainage-basin : draws water supply twenty-eight States Territories ; Delaware , Atlantic seaboard , country Idaho Pacific slope--a spread forty-five degrees longitude.', 'Mississippi receives carries Gulf water fifty-four subordinate rivers navigable steamboats , hundreds navigable flats keels.', 'area drainage-basin combined areas England , Wales , Scotland , Ireland , France , Spain , Portugal , Germany , Austria , Italy , Turkey ; almost wide region fertile ; Mississippi valley , proper , exceptionally.']
[{'associated': {'cover': 1, 'longitude': 1, 'journey': 1, 'contrary': 1, 'main': 1, 'world--four': 1, 'ground': 1}, 'keyword': 4}, {'associated': {'area': 1, 'france': 1, 'germany': 1, 'proper': 1, 'reading': 1, 'steamboats': 1}, 'keyword': 3}]
```

Comment: Hi Ajax, sorry to mention. Do you have solution without importing modules coz it is hard for me to read..just a beginner of python, sorry.

Comment: @JimYe A solution without modules would  *much* harder to read than what is currently posted for my answer. Is that requirement part of an assignment?

Comment: Yes, importing module is out of scope of practice. So far I learnt list, dictionary etc. and it might be easier to understand.

Comment: @JimYe `re` is member of the standard Python Library and should be included in any normal Python installation. So except for embedded applications, you can safely use it...

Comment: @Ajax1234 - great solution. Thanks. let me study it a bit. Some codes are difficult for me.

Comment: @Ajax1234 - Hi Ajax, i got the result from your output. But Could you help me to test my code coz my code is more similar to the output. i am now stuck at sorting the dictionary value by key and obtain every associated words for target word. Like word "river", it shows 4 times in whole paragraph and the associated words are "ground: 1", "journey: 1" and so on. The associated words are in the same sentence of target words. The practice is more likely to get the same output  as desired.

Comment: @JimYe Glad to help! Can you post the code you are having difficulty with?

Comment: @Ajax1234 - Hi Ajax, I have updated my code and its output in question. I get the occurrence of each word but failed to get it in descending order (most occurrence word come first). Also, I would like to treat each word as target word and count the associated words  and list like desired output. The associated words are in the same sentence as target word (use "." dot as full stop) in a full stop sentence. If one word happens twice or more in one sentence, treat it as one. Like target word "river", it happens 4 times in paragraph. The associated words are "ground: 1", "journey: 1" and so on.